# Stream media from Play Store on Android To PC

Tags: video, streaming

I was just wondering whether it is possible to stream play store content from android to your PC. I know there are ways to stream movies that are stored on the actual device, but I want to be able to stream movies that I might buy on the Google Play Store to my PC for watching when I'm at home.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: `"Watch them instantly on the web or your Android phone and tablet."` - This is from the [Play Movies home page](http://play.google.com/about/movies/). Is that not answering what you're asking? Is there a relation to Android or are you just trying to stream from the website to your PC?

Comment: Thanks I had no idea you could watch them on the web I thought it was only on an android device. The only thing though on the web it is not in HD its only 420p whereas on android it would be hd. I'm guessing hd isn't available on the web then. But is it possible to stream the hd version from the phone/tablet onto the PC so that it is in high quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can play movies straight from Google Play after you've bought them; Music, go to music.google.com and you can stream and download your music. If you want to get the HD versions, you can download on your phone/tablet and then pull it, I think. Never actually tried it with movies, but I've done it with music before.

Comment: It doesn't look as if you can download movies as they are only rented for a certain period of time. That's why I was wondering whether the streaming would work. Although, now thanks to @eldarerathis I know you can watch them online but its only in standard quality not HD which seems a bit strange to me

Comment: Oh, whoops - I forgot, you can only download them if you bought them, not rented them, and that's only available for certain movies, like Transformers, which came with my Nexus 7. My bad. :)

Comment: The last time I rented a movie from the Play Store it had a "Download and watch offline" option (a pin, I think) that expired after a viewing. So it was at one time possible to temporarily download a rented movie.